# Change Json structure on Azure Function log Archived into storage account

Tags: spring, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, log4j2

I have a huge problem with Azure Function log (on storage account) with Spring Framework + Log4j2 + JsonTemplate.

As you can see, I've activated the log archive on the storage account (blob storage) from the Diagnostic Setting of my function:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz5iJ.png)

and I correctly see these logs in .json files in the storage container:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXBuS.png)

but my logs are wrapped in a structure created by azure.

This is my local log (with Spring and Log4j.xml + JsonTemplate):

`{"timestamp":"2024-01-26T19:39:28.660Z","mdc":{ *** OBFUSCATED ***},"log.level":"INFO","message":"Message to log"}}","process.thread.name":"pool-2-thread-2","log.logger":"myLogger"}`

but in the azure json file I find:

```
{
    "level": "Informational",
    "resourceId": "*** OBFUSCATED ***",
    "operationName": "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/log",
    "category": "FunctionAppLogs",
    "time": "01/25/2024 13:56:56",
    "location": "*** OBFUSCATED ***",
    "properties": "{'appName':'myAppName','roleInstance':'*** OBFUSCATED ***','message':'the message that i see in local",
    "EventStampType": "Stamp",
    "EventPrimaryStampName": "*** OBFUSCATED ***",
    "EventStampName": "*** OBFUSCATED ***",
    "Host": "*** OBFUSCATED ***",
    "EventIpAddress": "*** OBFUSCATED ***"
}
```

So my question is, isn't there a way to log a custom structure into the storage json files? In this way I can decide to log the same structure that I log locally (in order to index it on Splunk)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Log Analytics recommends using Logic Apps for changing structure or adding any other custom logic to the transformation of the logs data in transit for export. Please review the following doc, specifically the use of Compose action which will come in handy for your use case: [Export data from a Log Analytics workspace to a storage account by using Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-export-logic-app)